# How can I join a university class conducted online as a non-matriculating student during COVID-19?

Tags: united-states, online-learning, covid-19, remote-work

I'd like to join a class at a university, as a non-matriculated student, that I can participate in online, due to COVID-19.  I already have a PhD (in a technical field), and am looking to take a class *outside* of a technical field, with the goal purely being personal intellectual enrichment.  Many universities are moving classes online due to COVID-19, which makes this practical.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  It's easy for me to find classes in the field of interest (Middle Eastern history) in various university catalogs, and it's easy for me to see if the university is holding it online or in person.  But I haven't been able to find out which universities will allow me to participate without being a degree seeking student.  I'm not tied down to any one university or any one particular class, but rather any class in my general area of interest that I can fully participate in.  I know that the application deadline for the upcoming semester is very soon (for cases where it hasn't passed).  Can you give me guidance on:

- What types of schools will allow such participation?
- What is the application process like?
- How do I find these?
- How do I go about doing this?

Note that I know there are a lot of open classes, MOOCs, Coursera, etc., but that's not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the full structure and engagement of a full university class, with papers that will be graded, and the like.

---

To clarify:

- *non-matriculated* means here "not seeking a degree", only (full) participation in a class
- I am happy to pay tuition for this class
- I'm located in the US

Comment: I believe this may be possible; once you find a university offering a class of interest, search their website for instructions on how to "audit" or "enroll as a nondegree student", and see if you can find the contact information of someone who would be willing to answer your questions. This will involve a fair amount of paperwork, and paying tuition -- which it sounds like you're happy to do.

Comment: Search for "non-degree" rather than "non-matriculating". That should turn up a site for many universities you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

> What types of schools will allow non-matriculated participation?

I'll skip this part, because honestly it was news to me that there are universities that don't do this.  Usually the emphasis is on job-related courses.

> What is the application process like?

Very simple, if you can pay.  They want your money.

> How do I find these?

Look for a "school of continuing education," "university extension" or similar.  If you do not want something job-related, you might look at programs marketed to retirees.  In some places, such as those with a shortage of classrooms during teaching periods, this may be easier if you look for summer courses.  Availability of classrooms is not, of course, relevant for online courses.

Comment: I thought this would be closed for shopping, but after seeing the other answers I'm not so sure.

Comment: -1 Non-matriculated means not enrolled

Comment: @user2768 That is incorrect. "Non-matriculated" means not enrolled *in a degree program*.

Comment: @user2768 Not quite. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matriculate https://www.dictionary.com/browse/matriculate

Comment: _to be formally admitted to study at a university or college_ Seems to mean _not enrolled_ to me. Only the OP can clarify, since the meaning varies between sources.

Comment: I did this to backfill some classes while I was preparing for my PhD curriculum. I had to enroll as a “non-degree seeking” student. The cost per credit hour was reasonable, although it did not give me access to many of the privileges that degree-seeking students were entitled to.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm looking for the full structure and engagement of a full university class, with papers that will be graded, and the like.

That is a big part of the work that goes into teaching. So the time you take up cannot be spent on "real" students. That would not be fair without some way in which you compenste for the effort. Setting up, administering, and enforcing such payment system is work, i.e. costs money. You can see that what you want is not that easy. MOOCs are an attempt to give something like what you want, but is still viable from the university perspective.

Comment: Universities do this precisely because it's profitable.  The students pay.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Indeed, that's what Maarten and I have both noted.

Answer (score -1):

For *(full) participation in **a** class*, rather than several classes, you may struggle. You could try institutes that specialise in remote learning / part-time study (and did so pre-covid), since they are more likely to offer single courses, especially those that target professionals. (My search provides [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=remote%20courses%20us).)

If you want to study a number of classes, but just not graduate, then you can simply enrol as a regular student. There's no requirement to graduate.

Also (as per my original answer to your now edited question): <strike>Beyond MOOCs, schools won't allow this. As [explained](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/155648/22768), it isn't in the financial interests of schools. Nonetheless, for a particular class that you're interested in,</strike> you could try emailing the instructor. If you present a good case, they may be willing to allow you to participate (just like they might allow you to participate physically). Whether you'll be successful is unclear: Participating physically would go largely unnoticed (in a large class), participating digitally may leave a digital trail (and isn't possible when students must login).

Comment: This is incorrect.  Enrolling paying students is profitable.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist _Enrolling paying students is profitable_: Indeed, I agree, that's what is written. What are you claiming to be incorrect?

Comment: @user2768 As far as I can tell, the original poster seems to be expecting to pay and happy to do so.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist and user2768 I think you're making opposite assumptions about whether OP is willing to hand over some cash.  OP hasn't actually specified either way.

Comment: @academic The OP wants to not enroll, which doesn't suggest a desire to pay

Comment: Only one assumption is reasonable.

Comment: No, they do not want to matriculate in a degree program.  That is not the same as not wanting to enrol, at least in certain countries.

Comment: @DanielHatton Surely universities can only collect payment from enrolled students. Nonetheless, I agree the OP hasn't specified either way.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You must have a different definition to me, looking to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matriculate#synonyms and  https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/matriculate, they're both aligned with my understanding. Nonetheless, perhaps certain countries use different definitions

Comment: This set up is quite common in the US. I know the OP hasn't specified the region, but are you trying to say that universities don't do this in the system you're familiar with?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim What is quite common?

Comment: @user2768 Allowing non-matriculated (non-degree) students to take classes in exchange for money. They are last in registration priority, so often there isn't room, but it is common.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim The OP has now edited their question. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now I'm confused, why would one class be harder than more? In any case, emailing the instructor would be inappropriate, because they would just direct you to the extension college or whatever unit manages NM students (if they even know about it). What system are you working from?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Universities (typically) offer many classes, not just one, so a non-standard request is surely less likely to be serviced. (Exceptions are universities that specialise, as noted.) Emailing an instructor works in the physical world, so why shouldn't it work in the digital (beyond the point I note).

Comment: What? That sentence does not explain your point. In any case, your answer is not correct for any university in the US I am familiar with. If you're unwilling to clarify what system you're working from, I am going to leave my downvote, as this answer is not helpful to the OP in achieving what they're looking for.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Which aspect _is not correct_? I haven't given a system, because my answer applies to several, including the US.

Comment: (1) There is no issue with registering for one class as opposed to several. (2) You cannot simply enroll as a regular student, to do that you have to apply and obviously someone with a PhD would not be accepted, and they would have to apply for the next cycle, and couldn't take a class this term. (3) "Non-matriculated" status exists so that someone doesn't have to apply as a new bachelor's student or whatever. (4) There is no need to email the instructor, you just enroll as an NM student and enroll in the class. You're proposing doing an end-run around around the system for no reason.

Comment: (1) Universities like to fill classes with students that take several classes. (2) Having a PhD (in a technical field) doesn't preclude enrolling for a degree (outside of the technical field) and the OP notes _the application deadline for the upcoming semester is very soon (for cases where it hasn't passed)_ (3) That's not my understanding of the word, but sure, countries differ, regardless, it doesn't preclude it. (4) I'm proposing an end-run for many reasons, including, it might be the only viable option. Anyhow, I'll leave it there.